# How to pip install packages into different versions of Python

Tags: python, pip

I have 2 Python versions

- Python 3.4.3
- Python 2.7.10

Env variable works with Python 3.4(in my system), so when I pip install`*package_name` it will only install the package into Python 3.4

I have a system variable for Python 2.7  -- `%python27%` -- also.

My question is; how can I pip install a package/module into Python 2.7 without changing the Env. Variable.

Note: %python27% pip install `*package_name` doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have multiple executables of pip.

Use pip2 and pip3 interchangeably.

Anyway, you should consider using virtualenv package, initialize it like `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 env_name` or `virtualenv-3.4 -p /usr/bin/python3.4 env_name` then each time you use your code, type `source env_name/bin/activate` and "python" should be aliased to virtualised version.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'll try as soon as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Created a virtual env for Python 2.7 and used `virtualenv -p /**path to python27.exe**/python27 env_name` so now it works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Will it also "alias" executables for other packages, like `pytest`, `pip`, `ipython` etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pip` for python2 and `pip3` for python3.
Also you can try using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) or [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was installing to Python 2.7 rather than Python 3.4. Using `$ pip3 install *package_name` solved the issue.