# How to install a package for specific python version

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two versions of python (3 and 2) and Python 2 is the default one, I want to install a specific package only for Python 3,

I am using windows 7

whenever i use pip install, it is installing python 2 package

How to specify which python version for pio install

Comment: Which OS you have?

Comment: I am using windows,

Comment: just use pip3 or another alias of pip for python3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pip install packages into different versions of Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660951/how-to-pip-install-packages-into-different-versions-of-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
python -m pip install package

python3 -m pip install package
```

This is how you would do it using pip for v2 and v4 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can use the following commands in command line:

```
# For Python 2
pip2 install package_name
# For Python 3
pip3 install package_name
```

Alternate way:

```
# For Python 2
py -2 -m pip install package_name
# For Python 3
py -3 -m pip install package_name
```